# nginx isn't parsing php in nextcloud install

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to set up a nextcloud server on a raspberry pi 3 (raspian stretch).

I've been generally successful in getting the stack built using nginx and mysql.  However, I've encountered a problem with nginx not parsing php.

That is, when I navigate to the pi's nextcloud install, the browser prompts me to open / save index.php (the next cloud login screen), which tells me the server isn't parsing it at all. I found one link to the nextcloud documentation which suggested adding:

```
index index.html index.htm index.php
```

to the nginx.conf file.  Unfortunately, it appears to have no effect.

Any tips on how I can go about troubleshooting this or other ideas to try?

EDIT: based on comments and first answer, I have updated my /etc/nginx

EDIT #2:  Reverted to the default nginx.conf file and added @Mason Stedman's code in his answer below to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.  Also, used the following tutorial (through step 7) to set up the stack after re-flashing raspian stretch:

https://linoxide.com/debian/install-nextcloud-10-nginx-debian-8/

For completeness, my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file is below.  For the server name, I had no idea what to put in, so I used the static IP address I assigned to it on my network (I'm not exposing this to the internet, BTW):

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name 192.168.xx.xx;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

       root /var/www/;
       index index.php index.html;

       location / {
            try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       }

}
```

Comment: Have you added the Nginx config ? - https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/admin_manual/installation/nginx.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your nginx config:

Edit:  Here is an example of the full thing you will need to put in there to work.  I can edit again if you need SSH support, or a more comprehensive example, but this example will work on just about any configuration.

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name site.com www.site.com;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/site.com.access.log;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/site.com.error.log;

       root /var/www/site.com/htdocs/;
       index index.php index.html;

       location / {
            try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       }

}
```

You need to send php files to a parser.  You can change the version in that to the version of php you wanna use.

Comment: Ok, so here's what I did:

1.  Added the nextcloud nginx configuration as suggested by @Tan Hon Tat (above) to the default /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file.  The nextcloud config was inserted in the http { } header section

2.  Added the location suggested above to the nextcloud configuration previously inserted.  Note I commented out the default "location / {}" declaration as it conflicted.

See the edit to my original post for details

Comment: Updated with a full example

Comment: Still no luck, I'm afraid.  I did a little more googling and noticed that one example pushed all of the server block stuff to /etc/nginx/conf.d/nextcloud.conf.  Don't know if thta matters.

I also noticed that nextcloud might need a config.php file?  I see there's a config.sample.php file buried in the nextcloud tree, but not sure where config.php would go.  I did find a suggestion or two on what that ought to contain, though...

Comment: The example I posted is about as simple as you can get with a generic nginx config, are you should php etc is installed on the system?  Posting what errors you're getting might be helpful.

Comment: Reflashed my card and started from scratch.  Followed the tutorial and set up /etc/nginx/sites-enabled as indicated above.  Now it asks me to create an admin user and database, tells me that MariaDB is all that's installed, but it's going to use SQLite anyway.  Can't get it to connect to the database...  but the access logs clearly show I'm running nextcloud...  progress, I guess.